# Drop rows with a 'question mark' value in any column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to remove all rows (or take all rows without) a question mark symbol in any column. I also want to change the elements to **float** type.

**Input:**

```
X Y Z
0 1 ?
1 2 3
? ? 4
4 4 4
? 2 5
```

**Output:**

```
X Y Z
1 2 3
4 4 4
```

Preferably using pandas dataframe operations.

Comment: `out = df.replace({'?': numpy.nan}).dropna().astype(float)`

Comment: It is the same as the answer below but very nice with a one-liner. Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try first find string `?` in columns, create boolean mask and last filter rows - use [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing). If you need convert columns to `float`, use [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
print ~((df['X'] == '?' )  (df['Y'] == '?' ) | (df['Z'] == '?' ))
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool


df1 = df[~((df['X'] == '?' ) | (df['Y'] == '?' ) | (df['Z'] == '?' ))].astype(float)
print df1
   X  Y  Z
1  1  2  3
3  4  4  4

print df1.dtypes
X    float64
Y    float64
Z    float64
dtype: object
```

Or you can try:

```
df['X'] = pd.to_numeric(df['X'], errors='coerce')
df['Y'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Y'], errors='coerce')
df['Z'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Z'], errors='coerce')
print df
    X   Y   Z
0   0   1 NaN
1   1   2   3
2 NaN NaN   4
3   4   4   4
4 NaN   2   5
print ((df['X'].notnull() ) & (df['Y'].notnull() ) & (df['Z'].notnull() ))
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool

print df[ ((df['X'].notnull() ) & (df['Y'].notnull() ) & (df['Z'].notnull() )) ].astype(float)
   X  Y  Z
1  1  2  3
3  4  4  4
```

Better is use:

```
df = df[(df != '?').all(axis=1)]
```

Or:

```
df = df[~(df == '?').any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: I get an TypeError: invalid type comparison

Comment: What is type of values with `?` ? Try check it `print type(df.at[0,'Z'])` - there is `?`

Comment: It works for one column. So it remove the rows fine for one boolean indexer. But as soon as I use | (or) it fails

Comment: Hmmm, maybe check `()`, it can be typo.

Comment: When I try and print out a ? mark it tells me this: KeyError: 0L

Comment: That did the work :) I used a loop instead of multiple rows of 'to_numeric'

Answer (score 5):

You can try replacing `?` with null values

```
import numpy as np

data = df.replace("?", np.NaN)
```

if you want to replace particular column try this:

```
data = df["column name"].replace("?", np.NaN)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Drop rows with a 'question mark' value in any column in a pandas dataframe**

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
 
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["col1", "col2"]) 
df.loc[0] = [ "foo",  "bar" ] 
df.loc[1] = [ "f?oo", "bar" ] 
df.loc[2] = [ "foo",  "?ba?"] 
df.loc[3] = [ "foo",  "?"] 
df.loc[4] = [ np.nan,  "bar"] 
print(df) 
 
df = df.replace("?", np.nan) 
df = df.dropna() 
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   col1  col2
0   foo   bar
1  f?oo   bar
2   foo  ?ba?
3   foo     ?
4   NaN   bar

   col1  col2
0   foo   bar
1  f?oo   bar
2   foo  ?ba?
```