# Remove row in Dataframe if Contains Question Mark Python 3

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I am newbie here so please forgive for any mistakes. 
I am trying to work on adult census dataset. I am finding it hard to remove the question marks in the dataset.

Link to the dataset :- https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data

I have also tried the 1st answer in the given link:- [Drop rows with a 'question mark' value in any column in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35682719/drop-rows-with-a-question-mark-value-in-any-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

But I am getting an error

```
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py in wrapper(self, other, axis)
   1251 
   1252             with np.errstate(all='ignore'):
-> 1253                 res = na_op(values, other)
   1254             if is_scalar(res):
   1255                 raise TypeError('Could not compare {typ} type with Series'

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py in na_op(x, y)
   1164                     result = method(y)
   1165                 if result is NotImplemented:
-> 1166                     raise TypeError("invalid type comparison")
   1167             else:
   1168                 result = op(x, y)

TypeError: invalid type comparison
```

Please tell me how to solve this issue. I am using Python 3.6

Thank You!!

Edit 1:- This is also called Census Income Dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First cast to strings and then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[(df.astype(str) != '?').all(axis=1)]
#alternative solution
#df = df[~(df.astype(str) == '?').any(axis=1)]
print (df)
   X  Y  Z
1  1  2  3
3  4  4  4
```

Or compare numpy array:

```
df = df[(df.values != '?').all(axis=1)]
```

**Details**:

Compare all converted strings by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) with change condition to `!=`:

```
print (df.astype(str) != '?')
       X      Y      Z
0   True   True  False
1   True   True   True
2  False  False   True
3   True   True   True
4  False   True   True
```

And then check if [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) `True` values per row:

```
print ((df.astype(str) != '?').all(axis=1))
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Could tell me what was wrong in the method I had used.                            df[~((df['X'] == '?' ) | (df['Y'] == '?' ) | (df['Z'] == '?' ))]                                                   Is this because I was comparing integer with string.

Comment: Doesn't this create a new dataframe? How do we drop rows "in-place"?  Something like `df[bool_mask] = []`. Thanks