# How can one filter a dataframe based on rows containing specific value (in any of the columns)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to limit a dataset so that it returns only rows that contain specific string, however, that string can exist in many (8) of the columns.

How can I do this?  Ive seen str.isin methods, but it returns a single series for a single row.  How can I remove any rows that contain the string in ANY of the columns.

Example code 
If I had the dataframe df generated by

```
 import pandas as pd
    data = {'year': [2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2011, 2012, 2015], 
        'year2': [2012, 2016, 2015, 2015, 2012, 2013, 2019, 2016],
        'reports': [52, 20, 43, 33, 41, 11, 43, 72]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'])
    df    

   year  year2  reports
a  2011   2012       52
b  2012   2016       20
c  2013   2015       43
d  2014   2015       33
e  2014   2012       41
f  2011   2013       11
g  2012   2019       43
h  2015   2016       72
```

I want the code to remove rows all rows that do not contain the value 2012.  Note that in my actual dataset, it is a string, not an int (it is peoples names) 
so in the above code it would remove rows `c, d, f, and h.`

Comment: `that contain the string`, what string?

Comment: You mean this? `df[~df.index.isin(['c', 'd', 'f', 'h'])]`

Comment: Editted the post to be more specific, no I am not trying to drop known rows.  The actual dataset is almost 80,000 rows and I need to filter to only find data involved with a single person, whose name may be contained in 8 possible rows

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/35682788/12411517. You can remove using ~ or compare inequality.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use [`df.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) with [`df.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) on `axis=1`:

```
df[df.eq('2012').any(1)] #for year as string
```

Or:

```
df[df.eq(2012).any(1)] #for year as int
```

---

```
   year  year2  reports
a  2011   2012       52
b  2012   2016       20
e  2014   2012       41
g  2012   2019       43
```

Comment: This code works, ALTHOUGH to any future readers please note that the answer snippet searches for a string (which is what my real dataset has) so it will not return the correct results on my example code where 2012 is an int

Comment: Ill be accepting this answer when the time allows, thank you so much for the quick response and the edits

Comment: To search for `'2012'` in specific columns only, use: `df[df.loc[:, columns].eq('2012').any(1)]`, given that `columns` is a list of columns in which to search (e.g. `columns = ['year', 'year2']`)

Comment: How would you go about modifying this to drop any rows which do not contain a substring. (rows in which no value satisfies 'string' is in values)

say for example I have a large dataset with names but I want to return all rows which contain the name george, but that may include different last names (for example, column 3 may be george foreman or george brazil, but i want both returned)

Comment: @AlbinoRhino may be `df.apply(lambda  x: x.str.contains('george')).any(1)` ? if not  that does call for a different question since this is asking for a substring match and not an exact match

Answer (score 0):

try simple code like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'year': [2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2011, 2012, 2015], 
'year2': [2012, 2016, 2015, 2015, 2012, 2013, 2019, 2016],
'reports': [52, 20, 43, 33, 41, 11, 43, 72]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'])
df = df.drop(['c', 'd', 'f', 'h'])

df
```

it will give you dataframe like this:

```
   year  year2  reports
a  2011   2012       52
b  2012   2016       20
e  2014   2012       41
g  2012   2019       43
```

Comment: I am not dropping known rows, but instead finding rows which lack a certain value in any of their columns, then removing them

Answer (score 0):

To find the dataframe made of the rows that **have** the value

```
df[(df == '2012').all(axis=1)]
```

To find the dataframe made of the rows that **do not** have the value

```
df[~(df == '2012').all(axis=1)]
```

or

```
df[(df != '2012').all(axis=1)]
```

See the related https://stackoverflow.com/a/35682788/12411517.

Comment: dataframe objects cannot use contains.  If you edit this post so that it doesnt have that ill remove the downvote of course.  Also if you can find a working method id give the upvote.

Comment: @AlbinoRhino sorry about that. removed.