# How can I return a dataframe after dropping rows which do not contain a substring

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataset and would like to filter it to only show rows which contain a particular substring (In the following example, 'George') (also bonus points if you tell me how to pass multiple substrings)

For example, if I start with the code

```
data = {
'Employee': ['George Brazil', 'Tim Swak', 'Rajesh Mahta', 'Kristy Karns', 'Jamie Hyneman', 'Pamela Voss', 'Tyrone Johnson', 'Anton Lafreu'], 
'Director': ['Omay Wanja', 'Omay Wanja', 'George Stafford', 'Omay Wanja', 'George Stafford', 'Kristy Karns', 'Carissa Karns', 'Christie Karns'], 
'Supervisor': ['George Foreman', 'Mary Christiemas', 'Omay Wanja', 'CEO PERSON', 'CEO PERSON', 'CEO PERSON', 'CEO PERSON', 'George of the jungle'], 
'A series of ints to make this more complex': [1,0,1,4 , 1, 3, 3, 7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'])
df

         Employee         Director            Supervisor  A series of ints to make this more complex
a   George Brazil       Omay Wanja        George Foreman                                           1 
b        Tim Swak       Omay Wanja      Mary Christiemas                                           0
c    Rajesh Mahta  George Stafford            Omay Wanja                                           1
d    Kristy Karns       Omay Wanja            CEO PERSON                                           4
e   Jamie Hyneman  George Stafford            CEO PERSON                                           1
f     Pamela Voss     Kristy Karns            CEO PERSON                                           3
g  Tyrone Johnson    Carissa Karns            CEO PERSON                                           3
h    Anton Lafreu   Christie Karns  George of the jungle                                           7
```

I would like to then perform an operation such that it returns the dataframe but with only rows a, c, e, and h, because they are the only rows which contain the substring 'George'

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, Ive tried various lambda statements and similar suggestions on my previous related question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59686701/how-can-one-filter-a-dataframe-based-on-rows-containing-specific-value-in-any-o

I could probably 'george' in str(df.iloc[x,y]) then loop over the dimensions x and y, having it return the row value when I see a true, then use that list as serialization to keep those index values.  But im looking for a more pythonic approach

Comment: That looks more like a duplicate than a related question, what’s different?

Comment: The linked questions marked answer uses equal, which must match eaxctly and which is part of the dataframe methods.  I need a substring, which could use str.contains or
 'value' in StringObject but applying lambdas this way isnt familiar for me so I need some help

Comment: maybe concanate all your columns and run the search 'Geroge' in the concanated column? Not sure it is more Pythoni though...

Comment: @AlbinoRhino Oh, that wasn’t obvious from the example code. Well you know about `.str.contains`, so you should be fine!

Comment: @AMC Should I just loop through each column in a try block so that columns which cant use str.contains are simply ignored??

Comment: @AlbinoRhino It’s better to hardcode the columns, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
filters = 'George'
df[df.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains(filters).any(), axis=1)]
```

## edited to return subset

Comment: Really like this solution.  Thank you for these pythonic pandas shenanigans.

Answer (score 1):

From your code, it seems you only want the rows that have `'George`' in columns `['Employee', 'Director', 'Supervisor']`. If so, try this:

```
# Lambda solution for first `n` columns
mask = df.iloc[:, 0:3].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('George')).sum(axis=1) > 0
df[mask]

# Lambda solution with named columns
mask = df[['Employee','Director','Supervisor']].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('George')).sum(axis=1) > 0
df[mask]

# Trivial solution
df[(df['Employee'].str.contains('George')) | (df['Director')].str.contains('George')) | (df['Supervisor'].str.contains('George'))]
```

Comment: Id like a more pythonic way, in case the dataset may have an unknown number of columns which may have it.  Id like to be able to check every row

Comment: I added an lambda solution. Maybe this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Both your solutions are great, and I gave an upvote for it, but how would I pass ALL rows in.  The actual dataset I have has 4 manager levels, and 5 leader levels, and depending on how projects are managed, the my filter needs to be able to check those.  There is also an employee level, contractor level and more which may need to be considered, so Id like a single solution that passes each column

Comment: Are the columns you are looking for the first few columns in `df`?

Comment: @AlbinoRhino Can you share a more accurate representation of the data, then? What do you mean by _level_?

Comment: For the sake of anonymity of my data I cant share a WAY more accurate version, I can just tell you there is manager level 2-5 and leader level 5-8 and supervisor and a few other fields which could contain the name I need to filter by, which could be input as a full name first then last, last then first, or last then shortened (for example tim instead of timothy)  and depending on the report Im running, some of these columns may not even exist.  So im trying to develop a more flexible filter method that take a substring (in my particular case, last name) and then all rows

Answer (score 1):

You can separate use an or statement for each column. There's probably a more elegant way to get it to work, but this will do.

```
df[df['Employee'].str.contains("George") | df['Director'].str.contains("George") | df['Supervisor'].str.contains("George")]
```

Comment: Ill give you an upvote for a good answer, however, my dataset may have an unknown number of columns, of which any number could have the substring im searching for.